# Ruby on Rails generate routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes, friendly-id

I am trying to generate routes in my rails app.
The app has Movie table and column genre. I want to make the routes like this: /movies-genre-horror and shows all the movies with genre horror. Is it actually possible? If yes, can anyone give a hint how to do it? I would be nice if there's tutorial to do it. I did make like this: /movies/genre/horror and it works. I use gem friendly_id and use slug to change the genre that not url friendly.

Comment: you could generate a fallback route, where you look inside the controller, if you get some matches in your database. But why changing default behaviour? I think it looks nice `/movies/genre/horror`

Comment: would you mine to elaborate? how to generate a fallback routes? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a default route to your `routes.rb`. At the very end just do a

```
match ":default" => "foo#default"
```

And inside `foo_controller.rb`

```
def default
  # here are your params
  parts = params[:default].split("-")
  controller = parts[0]
  action = parts[1]
  genre = parts[2]
  records = Movie.where(genre: genre)
  if records.count > 0
    # redirect to your controller aciton
  else
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
end
```

It's not tested, but I think you should get the point.